# CSS nested :not() selector

Tags: css, selector

I want to apply a set of css rules to all (One) lists within my #content div, but these can NOT be allowed to affect the (Two) lists in the additional div.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        #content *:not(div) ul {list-style:none;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <ul>
                <li>One</li>
            </ul>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>Two</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this specific scenario you could use

```
#content > ul {list-style:none;}
```

This will target **direct children** of the `#content` element

Comment: thank you, I had completely forgot that one. But any idea why the :not() doesnt work?

Comment: @Paul the `:not()` will not work because it implies another element between the `#content` and `ul` that is not a `div`. It is equivalent to `#content *:not(div) ul` and the `*` in there must match something to be valid

Comment: I understand. It implies *:not(div) so if the first div was surrounded by a span it would work.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the ["child" or "descendent" selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors), which matches only those elements on the right right of the selector `>` that are immediate children of elements matching the left. If I understand you correctly you want:

```
#content > ul { list-style: none; }
```

Comment: thank you, I had completely forgot that one. But any idea why the :not() doesnt work?